# Why variable-sized object can be initialized with (), and not with {} in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, most-vexing-parse

Why can initialize array **nums** with parentheses, but cannot with braces? Whats the difference here? I know **nums** is variable sized object and cannot be initialized, but I am not sure why it can be initialized with zeros using parentheses.

This works:

```
int n = 5;
int nums[n]();
```

This doesn't:

```
int n = 5;
int nums[n]{};
```

Comment: I think you have what works and doesn't work round the wrong way. At least, the second works in **Standard** C++ if you make `n` into `const int n = 5;`.

Comment: Syntax matters: `int nums[5]{{}};` Also, VLAs are illegal in C++.

Comment: This brace initialization is perfectly valid. However the specification of the array with a non-constant `n` is not valid standard C++.

Comment: In the first, you are attempting to declare an array of functions returning `int`.

Comment: @Dúthomhas not illegal, just not ISO standard C++.

Comment: If I compile your code that "works", I get "error: declaration of 'nums' as array of functions". The declaration says "`nums[k]()` is an `int`".

Comment: `int n = 5; int nuns[n];` is not standard C++. There's a lot of confusion because one compiler supports this as an extension but doesn't give (the required) warning. In any event, if your compiler allows a non-constant array dimension, you have to ask the implementors of that compiler for more details about what they did.